# Flask-sqalchemy and oracle database id not autoincrement

Tags: python, database, flask, oracle11g, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to make a new table in my database (Oracle 11g but the Express Edition for Ubuntu 16.04) using Python and Flask framework with the SQLAlchemy module. The first field of the table it's and ID, is an Integer field and I want it to autoincrement, but Oracle database don't support the autoincrement. I have a form to add a new comment, but when I try to add a new record it reports a error:

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (cx_Oracle.IntegrityError) ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("WIKTOR"."TBL_COMENTARIOS"."ID") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO tbl_comentarios (usuario, comentario, fecha) VALUES (:usuario, :comentario, :fecha) RETURNING tbl_comentarios.id INTO :ret_0'] [parameters: {'usuario': 'wiktor', 'comentario': 'hola', 'fecha': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 24, 11, 23, 45, 39450), 'ret_0': }]

Basically it says that the ID cannot be null, that happens because there's no field in the form to add it so it sends the id empty and then the autoincrement of the database model don't work. Here's the code:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Comentarios(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_comentarios'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    usuario = db.Column(db.String(50))
    comentario = db.Column(db.Text())
    fecha = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.datetime.now)

def __init__(self, usuario, comentario):
    self.usuario = usuario
    self.comentario = comentario
```

I also tried:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

That code did work in SQL Database but neither works in Oracle Database.

Sorry for my english, I hope someone can help me...
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html) the SQLAlchemy documentation that discusses this. Oracle has no auto increment feature and relies on sequence to mimic the behavior.

So, your id column should look like this:

```
id_seq = Sequence('id_seq')
id = db.Column(db.Integer, id_seq,
        server_default=id_seq.next_value(), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw that page, but don't get the idea clear. I add Sequence ('id_seq') but then I have to create a sequence? how I can do that?

Comment: Check the edited code for a clearer version that works without the need to create your sequence prior in your Oracle db. Also check [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#associating-a-sequence-as-the-server-side-default) guide for more detail.

Comment: thanks this may help me, but I don't understand the "metadata=Base.metadata"

Comment: The metadata is retrieved from your declarative base. Since you are using Flask-SqlAlchemy, you may bypass this entirely.

Comment: I have tested it without the metadata parameter and it works! Changed my answer to reflect that. I do not recommend running custom SQL code directly from the application to create the sequence, since this will cause trouble with migrations later on. It is better to do it with the framework directly.

Comment: I tried and it gives me this error 
NameError: name 'Sequence' is not defined
I need to import some modules or what did go wrong?

Comment: Yes, of course. Add ```from sqlalchemy.schema import Sequence``` at the top of your file.